# Having a checkboxes inside Listbox of jsf or primefaces

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

Hi what i  have  currently done is that i have make a list box inside which i m selecting user with `checkboxes` it's all done through html and javascript and css now requirement is that i need the same functionality with `jsf or primefaces` please tell me the way how to perform this or is their any already implemented functionality in `jsf or prime faces`

[image]

something like that i want ,that under drop down list box multiple checkboxes are there

```
   <h:selectManyListbox value="#{user.favFood1}">
            <h:selectManyCheckbox id="subscriptions" layout="pageDirection">
                <f:selectItem id="item1" itemLabel="News" itemValue="1" />
                <f:selectItem id="item2" itemLabel="Sports" itemValue="2" />
                <f:selectItem id="item3" itemLabel="Music" itemValue="3" />
                <f:selectItem id="item4" itemLabel="Java" itemValue="4" />
                <f:selectItem id="item5" itemLabel="Web" itemValue="5" />
            </h:selectManyCheckbox>
    </h:selectManyListbox>
```

Comment: Take a look at [selectCheckboxMany](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/selectCheckboxMenu.jsf) component of PrimeFaces.

Comment: @skuntsel  thanks for answer but i want the same scenario in jsf or prime as shown in figure.The link you gave is all about SelectCheckboxMenu my requirement is to have listbox like shown in figure not menu if any solution available will be very helpful thx

Comment: @skuntsel for the clarification of requirement i have add snippet of code , under drop down list i want many check-boxes this is the basic requirement

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this

`<p:selectCheckboxMenu value="#{user.favFood1}">`
`<f:selectItem id="item1" itemLabel="News" itemValue="1" />`
`<f:selectItem id="item2" itemLabel="Sports" itemValue="2" />`
`<f:selectItem id="item3" itemLabel="Music" itemValue="3" />`
`<f:selectItem id="item4" itemLabel="Java" itemValue="4" />`
`<f:selectItem id="item5" itemLabel="Web" itemValue="5" />`
`</p:selectCheckboxMenu>`

It will create a checkbox inside the dropdown.